# Reachable numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, decision-problem

## Definitions

- **Euler Phi Function** (AKA **totient function**): a function which takes in a positive number and returns the number of positive numbers less than the given number which are co-prime with given number. It is denoted as `φ(n)`.
- **Reachable number**: if there exists a positive integer `x` such that `φ(x) == n`, then `n` is **reachable**.

## Task

Write a function/program to determine if a given positive integer is reachable.

## Input

A positive number, in any reasonable format. One can assume that the number is within the capability of the language. Unary input is accepted.

## Output

Two consistent values, one for reachable numbers, and the other for unreachable numbers. The two values can be anything, as long as they are consistent.

## Testcases

The reachable numbers bellow `100` are:

> 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 28, 30, 32, 36, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 64, 66, 70, 72, 78, 80, 82, 84, 88, 92, 96

([A002202](https://oeis.org/A002202) on OEIS)

## Rules

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/48934) apply.

## Winning criterion

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Submission with lowest byte-count wins.

## References

- [Euler Phi Function](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Euler_Phi_Function)
- [OEIS A002202](https://oeis.org/A002202)

Comment: also relevant: https://oeis.org/A264739

Comment: I offer a bounty to a one-line Retina answer, where the one line is a plain regex (no backticks).

Comment: @LeakyNun I'm little confused, so far I understand that `phi(n) = count { m : 1 <= m <= n AND (m,n) are coprime }`.. is that true?

Comment: @Khaled.K yes, that is true.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
²RÆṪe@
```

Not exactly fast. Returns **1** or **0**.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39oU9Dhtoc7V6U6/Le0PNx@eELafwA)

#### How it works

```
²RÆṪe@  Main link. Argument: n

²       Square; yield n².
 R      Range; yield [1, ..., n²].
  ÆṪ    Compute the totient of each integer in the range.
    e@  Exists swap; test if n occurs in the generated array.
```

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: Brute force. There's a lower bound for the totient function, so it's enough to take a large enough range, map totient, and check for occurrences of the input.

Comment: Can you prove that the square root is the minimum?

Comment: The square root is actually not a lower bound, but the square root divided by sqrt(2) is. I'm positive that doubling is not required, but a proof will have to wait until I've gotten some sleep. Too tired right now.

Comment: This is a trivial modification, so I won't post it, but just out of interest, another possibility is to use `i:` for the last two bytes.

Comment: @LeakyNun Actually, lemma 3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.2068) proves that the square root is a lower bound unless **n = 2k** with odd **k**. Since **k** and **2k** have the same totient, doubling is not required.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino That *might* work (and if it does, I can double instead of squaring), but I'm not sure.

Comment: haha it looks almost like it says rate

Comment: I think your **R**ange can start from `n+1`, since `phi(x) <= x-1`.

Comment: @Khaled.K Well, yes, but that would cost two bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
EulerPhi@Range[#^2]~FreeQ~#&
```

Like Dennis's Jelly answer, we compute the φ-values of all the numbers up to the square of the input and see if the input appears therein. Returns `False` if the input is reachable and `True` if it's not. Yep, that's confusing. But `FreeQ` is a byte shorter than `MatchQ`, and hey, the spec said any two consistent values  >:)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>90</s> 82 bytes

Returns `0` or `true`.

```js
f=(n,x=n*2)=>x?(p=i=>(c=(a,b)=>a?c(b%a,a):b<2)(i,x)+(i&&p(--i)))(x)==n||f(n,x-1):0
```

This is based on the assumption that if ***x*** exists then ***x ≤ 2n***. If proven false, this should be updated to use `x=n*n` instead of `x=n*2` (same size, much slower).

An edge case is ***n = 128*** which requires to compute ***ϕ(255)***.

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,x=n*2)=>x?(p=i=>(c=(a,b)=>a?c(b%a,a):b<2)(i,x)+(i&&p(--i)))(x)==n||f(n,x-1):0

for(n = 1; n <= 50; n++) {
  console.log(n, f(n));
}
```

Comment: Conveniently the Fermat primes are all consecutive giving rise to consecutive edge cases `n=2`, `n=8`, `n=128`, `n=32768` and `n=2147483648`.

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 56 bytes

```
f(x:PI):Boolean==member?(x,[eulerPhi(i)for i in 1..2*x])
```

i don't know if it is right...test code and results

```
(35) -> [i  for i in 1..100|f(i)]
   (35)
   [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 28, 30, 32, 36, 40, 42, 44, 46,
    48, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 64, 66, 70, 72, 78, 80, 82, 84, 88, 92, 96, 100]
```

The range 1..(2*x) would be ok until input x=500...

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
nLÕså
```

Explanation:

```
n       Square [implicit] input
 L      Range [1 .. a]
  Õ     Euler totient
   s    Put first input at the top of the stack
    å   Is it in the list?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@5/nc3hq8eGl//8bGgAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 34 bytes

```
x->![n|n<-[1..x^2],eulerphi(n)==x]
```

Returns `0` if reachable, `1` if not.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#S1OwVfhfoWunGJ1Xk2ejG22op1cRZxSrk1qak1pUkJGpkadpa1sR@z8tv0ijAqjWUEfB0MBAR6GgKDOvBCiipKBrByTSNCo0NTX/AwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

**EDIT**: Saved a byte because input is reused if the stack doesn't have enough elements.

Outputs 1 if reachable, 0 if not.

Relies on assumption that x ≤ 2n if it exists.

```
xGNÕQi1,q}}0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@1/h7nd4amCmoU5hba3B//@GBgA)

How it works

```
              # implicit input    
x            # push input, 2 * input
 G           # for N in 1..2*input
             # implicit push input
  N          # push N
   Õ         # push totient of N
    Q        # check if both are equal
     i.      # if equal
      1,     # print 1
        q    # quit program
         }   # end if
          }  # end for
           0 # push 0 if condition never reached
             # implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 123 bytes

```c
g(a,b){return!a?b:g(b%a,a);}
i;r;f(n){for(i=2,r=1;i<n;i++)r+=(g(i,n)==1);}
t;k;s(m){for(k=m,t=0;!t&(k<m*m);)f(++k),t=(r==m);}
```

[**Try Online**](http://ideone.com/I1COys)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// gcd function
g(a,b){return!a?b:g(b%a,a);}

// Euler phi(x) function
i;r;f(n){for(i=2,r=1;i<n;i++)r+=(g(i,n)==1);}

// check if m is reachable, phi(x) for x in (m , m^2]
t;k;s(m){for(k=m,t=0;!t&(k<m*m);)f(++k),t=(r==m);}

main()
{
    // print all reachable number below 50
    for(int x=1; x<50; x++)
    {
        s(x);

        if(t)
        {
            printf(" %d ~ phi(%d) \n", x, k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [102 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY1BasMwEEX3PsUk4KKJZOIWsulE9CLdSI7sCFlKUBRiMO7VXdmh6V98GP7jTVN1TTPPHVNC4xhNusewUV/6s2O6VEIhTZYiJXJ0Yx7H9hKZk14kWVOUm/Tmjn7nKckopcdltZJzRx@VrSrCyGXHrHAo5TtNs1c2MCzGAnL2e7hGGxKovodoVHNWujcQ7l6bCNr0lwcc6hVdvZkcsgWG46HOzTmu21O25MYGpOJ12pYlfF3/2JL1ccu2UJ7gB65ny8oTwnfYChgEuKz5I6fi2dP8Cw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 63 bytes

```
> Input
>> 1²
>> [2]
>> φ(L)
>> Each 4 3
>> 1∈5
>> Output 6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hMvOTsHw0CYQFW0UC6LOt2n4aIIYronJGQomCsZgJY86OkxBDP/SEqAuBbP//80MAA)

Works by brute force. We square the input, then generate the range `[1, 2, ..., x²]`. Next we calculate \$\phi(i)\$ for each \$i\$ in this range. Finally, we check if the original input \$x\$ is in the array of  \$\phi(i)\$ values.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
┬$τ▀Ω♀
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=c224e7dfea0c&i=3)

I'm not sure why 3 golflangs have an Euler Totient function, but I guess it's convenient for these challenges.

0 for reachable and 1 for non-reachable.